# Program to find a specific prime number end in an infinite loop

Tags: python, math, primes

Hey guys i have a problem i wrote this code for projecteuler to find a specific prime number but
it in ends in an infinite loop i looked it up and found many alternatives but want to understand why this code just dosent work. Im new to programing so if you also have any tipps to improve my code i will appreciate them.

```
import math

x = 1   #number that is getting checked
y = 0   #indicator of how many prime numbers found
a = 0   #the most recent prime number
while y < 6:    
    for i in range (2, int(math.sqrt(x))):
        if (x % i ) == 0:
            x = x + 1
            break
        else:
            a = x
            x = x + 1
            y = y + 1
        break
print (a)
```

Comment: for everyone who is intrested this is the link to the problem https://projecteuler.net/problem=7

Comment: do you want answer for question in the link?

Comment: ah no like said in my question i found other solutiion but i would like to understand why my code ends in a infinite loop

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You put `x = 1`, and then loop on a `range` starting from 2: so the `for` is never executed, and the `while` loops indefinitely. You need to start with `x = 2`, or to handle the special case of `x = 1`

**EDIT**
The code works for `x` at least 9: the `for` loop is never executed until `int(math.sqrt(x))` is at least 3

Comment: hmm i just tried it wiht x = 2 or x = 4 but it still is a infinite loop

Comment: oh ok now it works and i see my error thanks